# Multiple Ansible archive(s) are not created

Tags: module, centos, ansible, redhat, archive

im trying to create 2 archives out of 2 folders by using archive module.

Unfortunately it´s not working without any error.

My tasks looks like this:

```
  tasks:
  - name: create a tarball of logfiles 
    archive:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_{{ item.name }}_{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.tar.gz
    register: ausgabe      
    with_items:
      - { name: 'xxxxxx', path: '/opt/jira/xxx/xxxxxx' }
      - { name: 'xxxxxxx', path: '/opt/jira/xxxx/xxxxxxx' }
```

Output:

```
TASK [create a tarball of logfiles] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxxxxx] => (item={u'path': u'/opt/jira/xxx/xxxx', u'name': u'xxxxx'})
ok: [xxxxxxx] => (item={u'path': u'/opt/jira/xxx/xxxx', u'name': u'xxxxxx'})
```

The tar.gz files are not created.

Can somebody help me on this?

Thx

Harry

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using variables or 'templating' your playbook make sure that you use " (inverted-commas) properly.

I have modified your archive module's statements and I got the required result.

```
  archive: 
    dest: "/tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_{{ item.name }}_{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.tar.gz"
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
```

Output:

```
myHost_xxxxxx_2018-06-12.tar.gz
myHost_xxxxxxx_2018-06-12.tar.gz
```